# How to use the java script method for different containers?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular8

I have made a container with some methods which functions when i click and hover to it, the problem is i have many different containers which requires the same methods, but i don't want to create many methods for the same work.

```
<div class="container" (mouseenter)="boxHide=false" (mouseleave)="checkBox()">
  image

  data
  data
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="xyz" [hidden]="boxHide">
    <hr>
    hidden. <button (click)="clickButton()">click me</button>
  </div>
  <div class="xyz1" [hidden]="hideDetails">
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
      <li>four</li>
      <li>five</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container" (mouseenter)="boxHide=false" (mouseleave)="checkBox()">
  image

  data
  data
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="xyz" [hidden]="boxHide">
    <hr>
    hidden. <button (click)="clickButton()">click me</button>
  </div>
  <div class="xyz1" [hidden]="hideDetails">
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
      <li>four</li>
      <li>five</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
boxHide = true;
  hideDetails = true;

  clickButton() {
    this.hideDetails = !this.hideDetails;
    this.boxHide = false;
  }

  checkBox() {
    this.boxHide = true;
    if (this.hideDetails) {
      this.boxHide = true;
    } else {
      this.boxHide = false;
    }
  }
```

```
.container{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: max-content;
}
```

For now if i hover to any one of the box both box are getting expanded, but i want the only specific one to expand. And there can be many boxes so i don't want to create many variables and functions for the same work.

Comment: you cannot manage state of multiple things with a single variable. consider using an array

Comment: can you help, how to use array in this?

Comment: there is an answer which uses arrays, and my recommendation is to create another component altogether

Answer (score 0):

You could use arrays to store the status of the boxes, e.g.

```
public boxHide: boolean[] = [];

public clickButton(index) {
    this.boxHide[index] = false;
}
```

And in the template:

```
<div class="container" (mouseenter)="boxHide[3]=false" ...
    <div class="xyz" [hidden]="boxHide[3]">
        <button (click)="clickButton(3)">click me</button>
```

And then index all your boxes etc. with individual numbers.

Comment: public boxHide = boolean[]; this line is not working

Comment: Indeed, it was supposed to be a type. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach may be to make a component out of the reused logic. If there are multiple boxes of the "same kind" abstract it into a child component and use it in the parent. This solves the problem.

```
<div class="container" (mouseenter)="boxHide=false" (mouseleave)="checkBox()">
  image

  data
  data
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="xyz" [hidden]="boxHide">
    <hr>
    hidden. <button (click)="clickButton()">click me</button>
  </div>
  <div class="xyz1" [hidden]="hideDetails">
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
      <li>four</li>
      <li>five</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could use arrays and indices or modify logic based on a unique id you could pass to each of the repeated containers, but that breaks the concept of reusable code and Angular as a framework